# cordova build IOS on windows

Tags: ios, windows, cordova, intel-xdk

Is it possible to build IOS app on windows using `cordova CLI on windows`.

Can intel xdk be used on windows & create app for `IOS` ?

Comment: no, it's not possible, you need mac os x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Intel XDK, the Cordova builds are performed in the cloud. So the answer is "yes" you can build apps for iOS using a Windows machine if you are using the XDK. In reality, they are built using a cloud-based Mac that has the Xcode dev system installed on it.

However, if you wish to use Cordova CLI locally, you need a Mac to build iOS apps. The XDK cannot change that, the XDK is simply a convenient front-end for developing, debugging and building Cordova apps.